# Connect to .net tcp server from http website

Tags: javascript

I need a way to connect to server (.net) not using node.js from browser ..I tried to use socket.io connection created but I can’t send and recieve using it

Comment: `socket.io` is for WebSocket protocol, you cannot connect to a raw TCP server from a browser, it has to be HTTP protocol if you use `XMLHttpRequest` or the `Fetch` API, or it has to be the RTC protocol, if you want to use the `PeerConnection` API. In node.js you can simply use the `net` module to connect to a TCP server, but as you said, you can't use node.js.

Comment: Can you give me example ..I’m really bignner in this field

Comment: I just said, what you're asking for is impossible. There is no example.

Comment: Sorry what about javasocketBridge ..can it solve my issue?

Comment: Not consistently. Looking at the project, it appears to be severely out of date, and it relies on Java, which is not enabled by default on most browsers.

Comment: Tell us more about what the .net server does. Is your .net program not capable of serving HTTP requests?

Comment: Last question after searching I found  artical about websockify that comunicate between tcp raw socket and websocket client

Comment: Yes ..The .net server not support http request ,we connect to it from .net windows application and mobile app ..and we need to make website to connect to the same server